# SQL auto update function

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, function

Say I've these 2 entities with n attributes-

```
         Cost                            Total

         ------------                    ------------
          cost_value                      total_cost
         ------------                    ------------
         |100       |                    |360       |
         |200       |
         |50        |
         |10        |
```

**Here the 'total' entity stores the sum of 'cost'. Now I'll insert data into 'cost' & automatically the 'total' will be updated with it's new sum value**.

Is it possible writing any function which will automatically be called and does the task I want? Or any other way(s)?

Comment: What DBMS are you using? What have you tried? I'd suggest that a view would be a better solution.

Comment: Using mysql. But I also want to use it in Oracle.

Comment: Currently I do it manually like- Insert into cost…. ; Update Total…..;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two ways to do this :

1. if you have a stored procedure that makes the inserts you can create another one to update the total and execute them in this order.
2. If the insert is made in multiple places (directly from an application and from several stored procedure), you can create a trigger on the `Total` table that makes the update and that is fired every time an insert/update/delete is made on the `cost` table.

Comment: Thanks for giving Idea about trigger. I got my ans here : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/25600/Triggers-Sql-Server

Comment: There is a third way in Oracle: materialized views.  Unfortunately MySQL doesn't support them (yet) but they can be simulated.  http://www.fromdual.com/mysql-materialized-views

Answer (score -1):

Weird approach, but in simple solution you'll have to have 3 SQL statements. First INSERT into  cost, then SELECT SUM (cost) and last UPDATE the total with summed value. [Example of SUM](http://www.tizag.com/mysqlTutorial/mysqlsum.php)

Comment: Currently I do it, but I want to make the UPDATE procedure automatic.